# Using a custom query in wordpress with paging

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm making an template and I need to write a fully custom sql query.

This is what I use right now but it doesn't work

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array($query, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged')));
```

I also use wp_pagenavi for pagination so I am a little limited.

```
wp_pagenavi(array( 'query' => $wp_query ));
```

Here is an example of a query that gets the most popular post (with the "Wordpress Popular Posts" plugin)

```
SELECT pl_posts.* 
FROM pl_posts  
INNER JOIN pl_popularpostsdata ON pl_posts.ID = pl_popularpostsdata.postid 
WHERE pl_posts.post_type = 'post' 
  AND pl_posts.post_date < NOW() 
  AND pl_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
ORDER BY pl_popularpostsdata.pageviews DESC 
LIMIT 0, 5
```

The problem is that wp_query just returns all posts and ignore my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the *paged* option without posts_per_page one would assume it uses the default number of posts per page from the blog settings.

Simply use:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array($query, 'posts_per_page' => NUMBER, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged')));
```